# Add a static value / line as a Series beside another databound series on ASP.NET MVC Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

I have build an ASP.NET MVC Chart for Diet website show the weights history for user, but I want to add the optimal weight as a continued line on the Chart, below example doesn't work because it give only one value and don't show the previous series "Default", Is there are any way to show the optimal weight as continues and static line on the Chart (above/besides the weight series)

```
  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Weight Chart";

    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet = FollowUpTBL.GetDS_FollowUpTBL(User.Identity.Name, 15);
    var dataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);

    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("My First Chart")

        .AddSeries("Default", chartType: "Line",
            xValue: dataView, xField: "FDate",
            yValues: dataView, yFields: "Weight")

        .AddSeries("default2", chartType: "Line",
             xValue: new[] { "optimal" },
            yValues: new[] { "85" }
            )

         .Write(); 
 }
```